# SQL Does Not Apply In Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I want to know the behavior that when you apply the changes in the sql outside the Automation,

It will be applied automatically in Automation?

Ex.
Automation[A] has sql activities.
I did want to stop the Automation itself so I applied the changes of sql activities outside the Automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I had a suspicion, but went ahead and tested this.  Suspicion was wrong.

Altering the Activity DOES change the running automation containing the query.

**reproduction:**

[image]

this is **recordsWithA** data Extension

[image]

the **recordsWithB** DE is the same, just contains a "B" record.
A third DE **result** has the same structure, but no records.

**Pre-run:**
Run this query once.

```
SELECT 
subscriberKey 
FROM
recordsWithA
/* overwrite result */
```

From this you get the "A" record in the "result" DE:

[image]

**Actual test.**

schedule the automation with the "recordsWithA" query for "in two minutes".

[image]

in the meantime, go to activities.

change the sql activity to pull records from "recordsWithB", not touching the automation in "overview".

```
SELECT 
subscriberKey 
FROM
recordsWithB
/* overwrite result */
```

After two minutes, go to Automation Overview.
Double check that your Automation ran for the second time:

[image]

Check the result DE - The result is now B:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort Jonas ! It's really good help to me.